# Is the following graph indeed planar

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

Consider the follwing graph

[image]

In the solution manual it says that this graph is planar. But I can't find an embedding in the plane. So my guess is that it is not planar and the solution is wrong

Comment: If a graph isn't planar, you should be able to find a subgraph homeomorphic to either K3,3 or K5.

Comment: I know Kuratowski theorem. But maybe the graph is planar and I can't find a drawing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a planar layout, it seems (original on left, embedding on right):

[image: graph layout created with yEd]

I found this first on paper, then using a graphics editor (yEd). On paper, I started with the two vertices of highest degree (a & f) as a pair, then added other vertices as necessary. An alternative is to pick a large cycle, then add paths of the remaining edges as bridges to the cycles.